# How can I get full match data for the last match in a string for a regex in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

[`Regexp#match(str, index)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-match) gives me the first match after `index` in string which is great for iterating through each match in from left to right. But how can I find the *last* match *before* a given index? [`String#rindex`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-rindex) gives the index of the last match but what if I want the full match data?

Example:

```
/.oo/.rmatch("foo boo zoo")
```

...should yield...

```
#<MatchData "zoo">
```

Comment: can you give any example data and what you'd want as the result?

Comment: The right most index of `"foo boo zoo"` is 10. How can you expect 12 as the result?

Comment: Do you want rlimit to control the last source string index which can be matched or the last index which can begin a match (allowing the match to extend past rlimit if it's first character is prior to rlimit)?

Answer (score 2):

You could limit how far into the string the regexp may match by sub-stringing the string.

```
irb> /.oo/.match("foo boo zoo"[0..-3])
=> #<MatchData "foo">
irb> /.oo/.match("foo boo zoo"[0..-3],3)
=> #<MatchData "boo">
irb> /.oo/.match("foo boo zoo"[3..-3]) # can also express the start with slice
=> #<MatchData "boo">
irb> /.oo/.match("foo boo zoo"[0..-3],5)
=> nil
```

[`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan) will repeatedly apply a regexp returning an Array of all matches, from which you just select the last one.

```
module RegexpHelper
  def rmatch str, rlimit = -1
    str[0..rlimit].scan(self).last
  end
end

Regexp.send :include, RegexpHelper

/.oo/.rmatch 'foo boo moo'     # => "moo"
/.oo/.rmatch 'foo boo moo', -3 # => "boo"
/.oo/.rmatch 'foo boo moo', 4  # => "foo"
```

Comment: +1, and if you add a negative lookahead, you don't have to iterate through the matches yourself: `/.oo(?!.*.oo)/`

Comment: This is fine if the regex is for a finite set (strings have known limited length).  It won't work if the regex has a Kleene star.

Comment: @EmilEriksson how would this not work on arbitrary regexp? the subslice limits the match to only consider input upto the high index of the slice, it cares not what the regexp _is_.

Comment: I'm not sure what I meant actually. You are right, this will work for arbitrary regexes.

But won't this be slow if there is a lot of text to match? It searches from the start up to the end of the string.

Comment: Yes, it must iterate up to the last match.  You could make a faster algorithm, but it would be far more complex.  You will need to logically reverse the regexp (not just reverse its string representation) then apply that regexp to the reverse of the string as @Gene suggests in another answer. It's not a trivial algorithm and gets especially tricky if you need to consider back-references and look-ahead|behind.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a monkeypatch solution:

```
class Regexp
  def rmatch str, offset = str.length
    last_match = match str
    while last_match && last_match.offset(0).last < offset
      break unless m = match(str, last_match.offset(0).last)
      last_match = m
    end
    last_match
  end
end

p /.oo/.rmatch("foo boo zoo")
#<MatchData "zoo">
```

Answer (score -1):

You could reverse the string, reverse the regex, and use `length(str) - index` for the start point.

```
1.9.3p194 :010 > /oo./.match("foo boo zoo".reverse)[0].reverse
=> "zoo"
```

Reversing a regex is simple if the language it represents is really regular.  Greediness or lack thereof can lead to edge cases you'd have to think through.

If the regex has a Kleene star, I believe this is the only way to get the job done unless you build your own reverse regex matcher, which is a big project.

Comment: This won't give you the right matchdata though, and that's kind of the whole point.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it.  What about the match data can't be easily "flipped" to get whatever is needed?

Comment: That's not what you did though. Also consider a regex like /"[^"]+"/ and a string like '"foo" "boo" "zoo" "'. In reverse it picks up a match that isn't a match going forward.

Comment: As I said, greediness causes edge cases.

Comment: Ok then consider something simple like /w+/, reverse it and get an illegal regex: /+w/ - It was a good idea but there's obviously too many problems with this approach.

Comment: You're trying to be obtuse. Don't literally reverse it. Logically reverse it.  For example `(abc)*` becomes `(cba)*` not `*(cba)`.  Reversing a regex is a homework problem in several textbooks on automata.  Check one out.

Comment: What's obtuse is defending this answer. Even if you go to the trouble of 'logically reversing' the regex you still have a solution that (when it works at all for 'non-edge' cases) gives the wrong matchdata.

Comment: @pguardiario while this answer's implementation is simplistic and won't work, the approach is actually implementable if you only consider pure regular expressions, I think.  If you need to also handle back-references and look-ahead/look-behind extensions, it's probably intractable. Some perl guy [tried to implement the fully general case](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=457762) seven years ago and seems to have given up without publishing his library.

Comment: Thanks.  Appreciate that. I did describe the limitations; this is certainly not a be-all/end-all solution. Rather in some novel situations it might be useful. Isn't that part of why we're all here?

Comment: We are here to determine the best answer to specific questions. Not to serve our own egos.